# Dropzonejs display file count

Tags: javascript

I am using dropzonejs on a website i'm working on, and so far it's working fine. However, I want to display the number of files below the dropzone-area so the user can see how many files they have added. I am also using a button to control the myDropzone.processQueue.

The problem I have encountered is that I can't get the total number of added files to show in the paragraph with id=output.

This is surely due to me being a newbie when it comes to JS, but I have tried setting the variable at different "places" in the script, to no avail.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script>

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {


  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,


  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    var count = myDropzone.files.length;
    });



            this.on("success", function() {

               myDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
            });


            this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {



                    setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
                title: "Thank you!",
                text: "Your upload is complete",
                type: "success",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok"
            }, function() {
                window.location = "index.html";
            }, 1000);
        });


            });
  }
};
</script>

<form action="send.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>

<p id="output"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

Comment: You can get it like this `myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length`

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry for the stupid question, but how and where do I implement that within the code? That's what is confusing me. Thanks!

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257864/1966247

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/basic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>


<form action="send.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
<p id="output">output</p>

<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");

    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
     
     var count = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length;
      output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.innerText = count;
    });

</script>
```